# What's really the practical difference between client:load and client:only directives in Astro?

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I have a React component within an Astro page calling the object `window` but it's getting broken because `window` is not defined when the page is using `client:load`, although it works with `client:only`.

[Astro docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#clientonly) mention that `client:only` and `client:load` act similar. So, respecting that I'm a newbie on Astro, I wonder why `window` is not defined when the page uses `client:load`.

If you are an Astro expert, would you gently explain the practical difference between these two client directives?

In advance, thanks!

**index.astro**

```
---
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import MyComponent from '@/components/ui/mycomponent'
---

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./favicon.icns" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
        <title>My App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <MyComponent client:load />
    </body>
</html>
```

**mycomponent.tsx**

```
const isHomePage = () => {
  const currentRoute = window.location.pathname;
  return currentRoute === '/';
}

export default function MyComponent() {  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        isHomePage() ? 'Home Page' : 'Other Page'
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the bug message, you need to use the React lifecycle, so your code will be like this:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const [isHomePage, setIsHomePage] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentRoute = window.location.pathname;
    setIsHomePage(currentRoute === '/');
  }, []);

  return <div>{isHomePage ? 'Home Page' : 'Other Page'}</div>;
}
```

for the difference between client:load and client:only check this [link](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/#hydrating-interactive-components)